# Implementing favorite button in Flutter Dart Firestore app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need some help, I'm developing a product page in a ecomerce app with a Favorite buttun to add to or remove from favorite products.

The problem with my code is that the boolean _isFavorite returns after the screen is alread built and the Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null is thrown.

How can I improve my code and make it work as intended in this case?

I have an add function and a remove function as below;

```
    // adds a product to users favorite list
  addFavorite(String currentUserID, Food currentFood) async {
    var _ref = _db.collection(_userFavoritesCollection);

    try {
      var _docRef = _db.collection(_userFavoritesCollection).doc(currentUserID);

      _ref.doc(currentUserID).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          // adds favorite if to existing product favorite map
          return _docRef.update({
            'favoriteProducts.${currentFood.id}': {
              "productName": currentFood.name,
              "productPrice": currentFood.price,
              "productImageUrl": currentFood.image,
            }
          });
        } else {
          // adds favorite if it does not exists
          return _docRef.set({
            "favoriteProducts": {
              currentFood.id: {
                "productName": currentFood.name,
                "productPrice": currentFood.price,
                "productImageUrl": currentFood.image,
              }
            },
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // removes favorite produc item form users favorite list
  removeFavorite(String currentUserID, Food currentFood) {
    var _ref = _db.collection(_userFavoritesCollection);
    return _ref
        .doc(currentUserID)
        .update({'favoriteProducts.${currentFood.id}': FieldValue.delete()})
        .then((value) => print('favorite item removed'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Feild to remove favorite item: $error'));
  }
```

Then I have a function that checks if the products is already in Favorites and return a boolean for the button to decide which function to flow when pressed.

```
// check if product is already in the users favorite list
  bool checkIfIsFavorite(String currentUserID, Food currentFood) {
    bool _isFavorite;
    _db
        .collection(_userFavoritesCollection)
        .doc(currentUserID)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.data()['favoriteProducts'][currentFood.id] != null) {
        print('Product is favorite for this user');
        _isFavorite = true;
      } else {
        print('Product is NOT a favorite for this user');
        _isFavorite = false;
      }
    });
    return _isFavorite;
  }
}
```

Product screen page;

```
// check if the product is already in the favorites list
bool _isFavorite = DBService.instance
        .checkIfIsFavorite(currentUser.user.uid, foodNotifier.currentFood);

// button on pressed
onPressed: _isFavorite
 ? () {
    DBService.instance.addFavorite(
    currentUser.user.uid,
    foodNotifier.currentFood);
   }
 : () {
    DBService.instance.removeFavorite(
    currentUser.user.uid,
   foodNotifier.currentFood);
   },
```

The way I understand it is the problem with is code is that the boolean _isFavorite returns after the screen is alread built and the Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null is thrown.

How can I improve my code and make it work as intended in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the button to show until the `_isFavorite` has loaded try
wrapping the button in a `FutureBuilder` then return the Button when the snapshot has data.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: DBService.instance
        .checkIfIsFavorite(currentUser.user.uid, foodNotifier.currentFood);
  builder: (context, snapshot){
     if(!snapshot.hasData){
       return SizedBox();
     }

     bool _isFavorite = snapshot.data;
     return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Fav Button"),
      onPressed: _isFavorite? 
         () {
           DBService.instance.addFavorite(
           currentUser.user.uid,foodNotifier.currentFood);
         }
         : () {
           DBService.instance.removeFavorite(
           currentUser.user.uid,
           foodNotifier.currentFood);
   },
  }
);
```

If you want to disable the button until the `_isFavorite` has loaded try this:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: DBService.instance
        .checkIfIsFavorite(currentUser.user.uid, foodNotifier.currentFood);
  builder: (context, snapshot){
     var _isFavorite = snapshot.data;
     return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Fav Button"),
      onPressed: _isFavorite == null ? null : ? 
         () {
           DBService.instance.addFavorite(
           currentUser.user.uid,foodNotifier.currentFood);
         }
         : () {
           DBService.instance.removeFavorite(
           currentUser.user.uid,
           foodNotifier.currentFood);
   },
  }
);
```